# Error installing Python package: make utility is missing from PATH

Tags: python, exception, pip, installation, package

I'm attempting to install pynacl on a new Windows machine with Python. Ran into the following error:

```
            raise Exception("ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH")
        Exception: ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH

        ---------------------------------------- 
Command ""c:\users\paul miller\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\PAULMI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wxwyakn7\\pynacl\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
    --record C:\Users\PAULMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-syh9a1l_\install-record.txt
    --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\PAULMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wxwyakn7\pynacl\
```

In an attempt to resolve the exception, I installed GnuWin and added the path to my user and system PATH variables.

I opened a new command window and verified that "make" executed. However, rerunning the install attempt with the following command resulted in the same exception:

```
pip3 install pynacl
```

What should I try next?

EDIT 1: added screenshot to show Make working

EDIT 2: Tried with easy_install as well, still getting the make error

[image]

Comment: Did you also restart the command window in which you ran `pip3 install pynacl`?

Comment: Yes. Just to be safe, I then restarted the machine. Still seeing the same thing.

Comment: Is your PIP up to date?  It should be pulling the prebuilt binaries from the windows wheel.

Comment: Yes: version 10.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this was an idiotic mistake on my part. Turns out I had installed a beta version of Python... Python 3.7.0b4, to be specific.

Doom on me.

I removed the beta and installed 3.6.4 and everything worked fine.

Oops.